# How to add timeout to a task in jBPM

Tags: java, jbpm, bpmn, business-process-management

I have a service task in jBPM. The process diagram is shown below.

[image]

I register the work item handler for the service task "Hello" as shown below using the default service task handler provided.

```
ksession.getWorkItemManager().registerWorkItemHandler("Service Task", new ServiceTaskHandler());
```

I am calling a java function from the service task. The function call an api and it takes almost 10 min to get the response. But before the task is completed, I get below error:

```
Jun 11, 2018 8:09:43 AM com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TransactionReaper check
WARN: ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX 0:ffff0a923832:e68d:5b1e2e09:19 in state  RUN
Jun 11, 2018 8:09:43 AM com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction checkChildren
WARN: ARJUNA012095: Abort of action id 0:ffff0a923832:e68d:5b1e2e09:19 invoked while multiple threads active within it.
Jun 11, 2018 8:09:43 AM com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction checkChildren
WARN: ARJUNA012381: Action id 0:ffff0a923832:e68d:5b1e2e09:19 completed with multiple threads - thread main was in progress with java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)
org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:282)
Jun 11, 2018 8:09:43 AM com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.CheckedAction check
WARN: ARJUNA012108: CheckedAction::check - atomic action 0:ffff0a923832:e68d:5b1e2e09:19 aborting with 1 threads active!
WARNING: Unable to put resource app-updateable-resource value [] due to No transaction is running
Jun 11, 2018 8:10:18 AM org.drools.persistence.PersistableRunner rollbackTransaction
WARNING: Could not commit session
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Process instance 131[com.sample.bpmn.hello] is disconnected.
```

How can I solve this issue. Is it a timeout issue. If yes, how can I increase the timeout

Comment: Do you want jBPM engine to wait for the completion of Service Task ?  If you are fine with executing process instance further then you can make a task as a async. Or you can write your own custom workItemHandler.

Comment: yes i want the engine to wait until the process is completed no matter how long it takes. Now it ends almost after 60 sec. How can I make task async? or What are the steps to create custom work handler. @Abhijit

Comment: Refer to https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_bpm_suite/6.4/html-single/user_guide/index#sect_domain_specific_tasks for creating custom workItemHandler. If we mark task as a async then engine will not wait for completion of ServiceTask, so you can ignore this approach.